# How do I keep a glob from copying a file in Cromwell / WDL

Tags: wdl

Using Crowell 52.  When I do a glob to get matching files, Cromwell places a copy of each matching file in the glob-* directory.

As these are multi-gigabyte Bam files, I'd really prefer for Cromwell to store soft links to the files, rather than full copies.

The code:

```
   output {
      Array[File] Outputs = glob("*.fastq.gz")
   }
```

Is it possible to make this happen?

Comment: It would help your case to show the code you're using.

Comment: @RamRS added above

Answer (score 1):

As stated in https://github.com/broadinstitute/cromwell/issues/4395

The problem may be because you can't hardlink folders on your system for various reasons (i.e. filesystem doesn't allow hardlinking folders, only files,  or you are trying to link between different filesystems).

You can try overriding the default way glob works.

i.e. add this to your cromwell.config

```
glob-link-command = "ls -L GLOB_PATTERN 2> /dev/null | xargs -I ? ln -s ? GLOB_DIRECTORY"
```

Like this

```
backend
{
  default = "Slurm"
  providers
  {
    Htcondor {
      actor-factory = "cromwell.backend.impl.sfs.config.ConfigBackendLifecycleActorFactory"

      config
      {
        glob-link-command = "find GLOB_PATTERN 2> /dev/null | xargs -I ? ln -s ? GLOB_DIRECTORY"
```